# How to modify a cookie from NSURLRequest in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hi I need to modify a cookie, but I'm developing in iOS, somebody knows how to change it. Maybe in UIWebViewDelegate with webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:??

Comment: Give us a little more detail here. Do you already have the cookie? What is setting the cookie? What kind of modifications do you need to make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the WebKit.framework is not available for IOS, the best way was to use the events to UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest and webViewDidFinishLoad, there I use NSHTTPCookieStorage class for the cookie and there modify it as below

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *sharedHTTPCookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies = [sharedHTTPCookieStorage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString]];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [cookies objectEnumerator];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
while (cookie = [enumerator nextObject])
{
    if ([[cookie name] isEqualToString:key]) 
    {
        NSString *actcookie = [cookie value];
        NSMutableString *newcookiestring = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@changes",actcookie];
        NSMutableDictionary *propscook = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: [cookie properties]];
        [propscook setObject:newcookiestring forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
        NSHTTPCookie *newcookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:propscook];

        [sharedHTTPCookieStorage setCookie:newcookie];

        return [cookie value];
    }
}
return nil;
```

Comment: The "propiedades" should really be "propscook", right?